# CSS selector to apply rules to an element if before another element

Tags: css, webkit

I'm looking for a way to apply some CSS to elements differently, depending on what follows it.  For example, with this HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="title">Some Title</span>
    <span class="subtitle">With Some Subtitle</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="title">Only a Title</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to apply different rules to `.title` depending on wether or not there is a `.subtitle`.

The closest I can figure out is the adjacent sibling selector

```
.title + .subtitle { /* rules */ }
```

But that applies the rules to the `.subtitle` elements that are preceded by a `.title`.  Instead I want the rule to apply to `.title` elements with a `.subtitle` element after it.

NOTE: it's not vital this is widely supported by browsers for my current usage.  My only target that matters is webkit based at the moment.

Comment: You might want to consider using Jquery

Comment: That seems like cheating for something that feels like I should be able to do with a snazzy selector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no sibling-combinator for "older" siblings in the [CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#sibling-combinators).

In this case, you might be able to get away with `:only-child`.

```
li > span.title:only-child { /* rules */ }
```

Comment: This works in this particular case.  Thanks.  Though it would be pretty awesome if that qualified selector actually worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would require backtracking in the layout engine and thus isn't available. you could do this in jQuery rather simply however:

```
$('span.title + span.subtitle').prev().addClass('cssClass')
```